# How to make SCNNode is always toward to ARFrame.camera

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit

```
- (void)session:(ARSession *)session didUpdateFrame:(ARFrame *)frame {
    SCNNode *shipNode = self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.childNodes[0];
    if (shipNode) {
        shipNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3FromFloat3(frame.camera.eulerAngles);
    }
}
```

I want to change ship's orientation with camera's moving, but the above code seems useless.

Answer (score 2):

Use an SCNBillboardConstraint to keep one node pointed toward another node.

Comment: Great!Thanks a lot!